# Javascript collapsable div not working?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to toggle the div to make it visible/hidden. Im making a leader board of sorts that i want to open but only when clicked.

```
<html>
    <title>test</title>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!-- the function -->
            function showleaders() {
                if (document.getElementById('leaderboard').style.visibility = "hidden";) {
                    document.getElementById('leaderboard').style.visibility = "visible";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('leaderboard').style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #leaderboard {
                height: 300px;
                width:300px;
                left:0;
                background:red;
                border-radius:20%;
                visibility:hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="javascript:showleaders();">Leaderboard</a>
        <div id="leaderboard">hello</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

What am i doing wrong?
I just want the div to toggle in between visibilities

Comment: What's not working? Do you get an error message? Elaborate on this question

Comment: jquery, would make it simpler. think about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the equals sign in this line:

```
if(document.getElementById('leaderboard').style.visibility= "hidden";)
```

To a double equals, and remove the semicolon. Try this:

```
if(document.getElementById('leaderboard').style.visibility=="hidden")
```

A single equals *sets* the value, a double equals *compares* the value.

Comment: you beat me! you did faster than I ;)

Comment: I prefer not to think of this as a competition, but yes, I did beat you :P

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function showleaders() {
   if (document.getElementById('leaderboard').style.visibility == "hidden") {
       document.getElementById('leaderboard').style.visibility = "visible";
   } else {
       document.getElementById('leaderboard').style.visibility = "hidden";
   }
}
```

Comment: What effect does the semicolon at the end of the `if` condition have, if any? Or should it be removed?

Comment: OK. I wasn't sure, and I was too lazy to throw some code together to check.